# generate field-value frequency count with jq

Tags: json, stream, histogram, jq, summary

I can query all the unique values from a JSON field like so:

```
$ cat all.json | jq '.complianceState' | sort | uniq

"compliant"
"configManager"
"inGracePeriod"
"noncompliant"
"unknown"
```

And I can pedantically query the frequency count of each of these unique field values like so:

```
$ cat all.json | jq '.complianceState' | grep '^"configManager"$' | wc -l

116
```

Is there a way within `jq` to do this all in one shot to produce output like this:

```
{
    "compliant" : 123000,
    "noncompliant" : 2000,
    "configManager" : 116
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my standard library:

```
# bag of words
# WARNING: this is not collision-free!
def bow(stream): 
  reduce stream as $word ({}; .[($word|tostring)] += 1);
```

With this, you could use the filter:

```
bow(inputs | .complianceState)
```

in conjunction with the -n command-line option.

#### In summary

One way to pull all this together would be to place the above lines of jq in a file, say bow.jq, and invoke jq as follows:

```
jq -n -f bow.jq all.json
```

Another would be to use the module system -- see the jq manual and/or [Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) for details.

Comment: I'm new to `jq` (brew installed it on MacOS) - how does one add custom plugins like this `bow` function, so the `jq` tool will pick it up?

Comment: Please see update; the relevant section in the Cookbook is https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#include-or-import-a-module-and-call-its-functions

Comment: Getting closer. When I run `jq -f bow.jq all.json` I get this (brief) snippet of output: https://pastebin.com/ThmQfrTw - so it's assigning 1 to each occurrence  - but is not tallying.

Comment: The update provides an example of how to use `inputs` to handle your stream.

Comment: You are a superstar! Latest update worked perfectly:  https://pastebin.com/EvDM95kA Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I uses, which a custom frequency function, that:

- buckets/bins an array of JSON values/objects by a JQ expression (the bucket `key`)
- provides the bucket `count` (frequency)
- provides the `percentage` of items for each bucket (rounded to 2 decimal places)
- provides the original `items` which were binned into the bucket, and
- sorts the buckets by their `count` in descending order.

```
def freq(expr):
  length as $total_count
    | group_by(expr)
    | map({
        key: (.[0] | expr),
        count: length,
        percent: (((length / $total_count * 10000 + 0.5) | floor) / 100),
        items: .
      })
    | sort_by(-.count)
  ;
```

For instance, having defined the above in my `$HOME/.jq`, the query:

```
jq -n '
[                                                                                                                                                                                               
  {"complianceState": "a", "other": 0.5},
  {"complianceState": "b", "other": 1.2},
  {"complianceState": "a", "other": 1.7},
  {"complianceState": "c", "other": 5.3},
  {"complianceState": "b", "other": 1.5},
  {"complianceState": "e", "other": 0.6},
  {"complianceState": "c", "other": 3.4},
  {"complianceState": "c", "other": 5.9}
] | freq(.complianceState)'
```

Would produce

```json
[
  {
    "key": "c",
    "count": 3,
    "percent": 37.5,
    "items": [
      {"complianceState": "c", "other": 5.3},
      {"complianceState": "c", "other": 3.4},
      {"complianceState": "c", "other": 5.9}
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "a",
    "count": 2,
    "percent": 25,
    "items": [
      {"complianceState": "a", "other": 0.5},
      {"complianceState": "a", "other": 1.7}
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "b",
    "count": 2,
    "percent": 25,
    "items": [
      {"complianceState": "b", "other": 1.2},
      {"complianceState": "b", "other": 1.5}
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "e",
    "count": 1,
    "percent": 12.5,
    "items": [
      {"complianceState": "e", "other": 0.6}
    ]
  }
]
```

For your case, you would need to slurp up the input into a JSON array with `-s`. From there, you can transform the output into the desired format. E.g.

```
jq -s 'freq(.complianceState)
  | map({key, value: .count})
  | from_entries
' all.json
```

Note that with the `freq` function you can group by an arbitrary expression. For example `freq((.other / 1.5) | floor)` if you wish to get histogram-like binning.